# Makefile: how to use command output as target name?

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
:PHONY Darwin Xcode Linux Cygwin

all: `uname`

Cygwin:
    echo "Making Cygwin"
    Scripts/Make/MakeCygwin.sh  

Linux:
    echo "Making Linux"
    Scripts/Make/MakeLinux.sh

Darwin:
    echo "Making Darwin"
    Scripts/Make/MakeDarwin.sh

Xcode:
    echo "Making Xcode"
    Scripts/Make/MakeXcode.sh
```

It doesn't work however:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target ``uname`', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

It turns out that the `uname` command isn't executed. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make's function extensions allow you to use $(shell uname).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
UNAME=$(shell uname)

all: ${UNAME}
```

You can find more useful functions here: http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html#ToC11